# SOAP server in Symfony 2 project

Tags: php, symfony, soap, soapserver

Im trying to implement WebService using SOAP in Symfony 2 framework. On server side im setting class to my server (setClass() method) becouse i need to make more operations on one instance of class.
If i used setObject for soapCalls, it works good,

```
use path\to\Test;
public function indexAction()
{
    $server = new \SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "http://test-uri.cz/"));
    $server->setObject($this->get('my_service'));
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    ob_start();
    $server->handle();
    if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
        $response->setContent(ob_get_clean());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

but doesn`t work with setClass method.

```
use path\to\Test;
public function indexAction()
{
    $server = new \SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "http://test-uri.cz/"));
    $server->setClass('Test');
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    ob_start();
    $server->handle();
    if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
        $response->setContent(ob_get_clean());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Can somebody gives me any hints?

Comment: I use setObject too. Your service is an instance of a class, so an object... I guess we can use setClass if your soap manager does not have any complex dependency as a service may have...

Comment: But setObject create new instace of class, when you call __soapCall method. And Im testing setClass on some simple class which has no dependencies and contains some simple method. So there can`t be problem with complex class.

Comment: I think it does NOT create new instance, but use an existing instance (an existing object) ! setClass does create a new instance.

Comment: Yes... so every new __soapCall, gives another instance... so i cant make more operations on one instance.

Comment: That would be great if somebody could confirm, but I'm pretty sure of that.

Comment: I tried it on setter and getter methods. One __soapCall with method, which set some class variable and second __soapCall with method, which get setted class variable.

Comment: Anybody with some hint?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SoapServer::setClass, you must state each parameters of the constructor of your service, and state the class name **with a full namespaced string** :

```
$server->setClass('Acme\YourBundle\SoapManager', $arg0, $arg1, $arg2 /*, ... */);
```

Comment: I know. As i said, for test purpose, i created simple class with no constructor... so I dont`t need any arguments.

Comment: I tried insert namespace string with class name into "use" above the class and into setClass() method too, but still im getting Internal Error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works... I had bad namespace and in SOAP server is need to use setPersistence() method after setClass().